# %u200E appears on my link when i dont want it to appear c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to make a part of my webisite link into arabic language so i have t use leftToRight Char to set the direction of the url but after i used it it placed on the Url %u200E when i dont need it because the url will fail to redirect to my correct path

I used this code it an Example from the internet

```
string followUpFormula = "FIF";
string renewAbbreviation =  "ع.ت" ;
var lefttoright = ((Char)0x200E).ToString();
var result = 10 + "/" + abbreviation + lefttoright + "/" + 2016;
```

lefttoright  is placing %u200E into my url how to avoid placing it on the url ?

Comment: I suspect the code which you have posted is insufficient to reproduce the issue (what is the value of abbreviation variable where you have declared it). Replacing abbreviation with renewAbbraviation in the result i get the value as "10/ع.ت‎/2016"

Comment: what is `abbreviation` content?

Comment: I think your code is incomplete. Are you trying to add a date on arabic format as part of the url?